# Why can't my mxmlc find the SDK home?

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to compile from the command line with mxmlc.

I am using a config file so am running something like this:

```
d:\myProject>mxmlc -load-config=myProject-config.xml
```

My config file includes reference to files that are located in the SDK underneath $FLEX_HOME\frameworks such as the \themes and \libs folder.

But mxmlc complains that it cannot find these files.

I have a %FLEX_HOME% environment variable defined and pointing to the top level of the SDK which includes the \frameworks and \bin folders directly underneath.   I also have %FLEX_HOME%\bin on the %path%.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just keep the relative paths, like in the original flex-config.xml?

Comment: are you 100% that paths are set correct? I see no reasons it should not work. What if you <run> %FLEX_HOME% , do you get the right sdk folder opened ?

Comment: Hi RIAstar - I am using relative paths.  myProject-config.xml was generated by doing a dump-config and has the same stucture as the original flex-config.xml.    Adrian - I am pretty confident that I have %FLEX_HOME% correctly setup to the top of the SDK folder.   This really should work and I am starting to suspect that there is something wrong with my JDK or my Windows install.   I am going to try on another machine.  Thank you both for your comments.